# concurrent transaction java hibernate then record the data

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have this situation. I record history usage of balance, the flow like this:
Account A create transaction have original balance like 5000, then create transaction for 1 amount then i substract 5000 with that amount then store to database 5000 - 1 = 4999 :

```
id | current_balance | Date
1          4999        2019-09-02 05:15:25.2123
```

Other case, A have quick transaction like 3 transaction and almost have same time (just different of millisecond). 
transaction 1 : 2019-09-02 05:15:30.3331 amount 1
transaction 2 : 2019-09-02 05:15:30.3412 amount 1
transaction 3 : 2019-09-02 05:15:30.3455 amount 1
so all of the 3 transaction query check balance original is 5000 then :

```
id | current_balance | Date
1          4999        2019-09-02 05:15:25.2123
2          4999        2019-09-02 05:15:30.3331
3          4999        2019-09-02 05:15:30.3412
4          4999        2019-09-02 05:15:30.3455
```

not like this :

```
 id | current_balance | Date
 1          4999        2019-09-02 05:15:25.2123
 2          4998        2019-09-02 05:15:30.3331
 3          4997        2019-09-02 05:15:30.3412
 4          4996        2019-09-02 05:15:30.3455
```

this my code :

```
BigDecimal singleBalance = invoiceItemsDao.getSingleBalance(jsonRecv.getString("externalkey"), tenantApiKey.getRecord_id());


if(BigDecimal.valueOf(jsonRecv.getLong("amount")).compareTo(singleBalance) == 1)
   {
        notif="Balance not enought";
        jo.put("result", "05");
        jo.put("notif", notif);
        LogSystem.info(request, jo.toString());
        return jo;
   }


 else
   {
        InvoiceItemsDao ido = new InvoiceItemsDao(db);

        String accountid = ido.getAccountId(jsonRecv.getString("externalkey"), tenantApiKey.getRecord_id());

        BigDecimal balance = ido.getBalance(accountid);

        LogSystem.info(request, "Balance before transaction : " + ido.getBalance(accountid));

        Invoices invoices = new Invoices();
        InvoiceItems invoiceItemsUSAGE = new InvoiceItems();
        InvoiceItems invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ = new InvoiceItems();

        Accounts ac = ado.findByExternalKey(jsonRecv.getString("externalkey"), tenantApiKey.getRecord_id());
        Tenant tn = tdo.findByID(tenantApiKey.getRecord_id());

        invoices.setAccount_id(ac.getId());
        invoices.setAccount_record_id(ac);
        invoices.setCreated_date(new Date());
        invoices.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        invoices.setInvoice_date(new Date());
        invoices.setTenant_record_id(tn);
        invoices.setTarget_date(new Date());
        invoices.setStatus("COMMITTED");

        db.session().save(invoices);

        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setAccount_id(ac.getId());
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setAccount_record_id(ac);
                        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(jsonRecv.getLong("amount")));
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setCreated_date(new Date());
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setDescription("Transaction DS");
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setInvoice_id(invoices.getId());
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setTenant_record_id(tn);
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setType("USAGE");
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setUsage_name("Usage");
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setPhase_name("Prepaid");
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setStart_date(new Date());
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setEnd_date(new Date());
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setCurrent_balance(balance .subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(jsonRecv.getLong("amount"))));
        invoiceItemsUSAGE.setExternal_key(ac.getExternal_key());

        db.session().save(invoiceItemsUSAGE);

        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setAccount_id(ac.getId());
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setAccount_record_id(ac);
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(-jsonRecv.getLong("amount")));
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setCreated_date(new Date());
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setDescription("Transaction DS");
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setInvoice_id(invoices.getId());
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setTenant_record_id(tn);
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setType("CBA_ADJ");
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setUsage_name("Usage");
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setPhase_name("Prepaid");
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setStart_date(new Date());
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setEnd_date(new Date());
        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setCurrent_balance(balance .subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(jsonRecv.getLong("amount"))));
                        invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ.setExternal_key(ac.getExternal_key());

        db.session().save(invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ);

        tx.commit()
}
```

this function query check last balance :

```
public BigDecimal getSingleBalance(String external_key, long tenant)
    {
        return (BigDecimal) session.createQuery("select SUM(i.amount) as amount from Accounts a, InvoiceItems i, Tenant t WHERE a.record_id = i.account_record_id AND t.record_id=a.tenant_record_id  AND a.external_key='"+external_key+"' AND i.tenant_record_id = '"+tenant+"' AND i.type='CBA_ADJ' group by i.tenant_record_id, t.record_id").setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ).setTimeout(300).uniqueResult();
    }


public BigDecimal getBalance(String accountid)
    {
        return (BigDecimal) session.createSQLQuery("select SUM(amount) from invoice_items WHERE account_id = '"+accountid+"' AND type='CBA_ADJ' ").uniqueResult();
    }
```

any clue ?

what i try to handle this use trigger on database, when new data was inserted i update the current balance, but that still give wrong result. the function :

```
create or replace function function_update_currentbalance() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN

    update invoice_items set tesbalance=(SELECT SUM(case when amount >= 0 then amount when amount <= 0 then amount end) FROM invoice_items WHERE id=id and type=new.type and account_id=new.account_id) WHERE id=new.id;

  return null;
END;
$$
;
```

Comment: How do you ensure that `ido.getBalance(accountid)` always returns the latest entry?

Comment: if no have any value stored, that function always get latest value before other value was commit ?

Comment: Please don't use names like `invoiceItemsCBA_ADJ`, `invoiceItemsUSAGE`.